React native project version 0.75.2 in setting.gradle file in secon line error
enter image description here
gradle clean but not clean gradle and new project bulid and npm start gradle version install and after show the error seeting.gradle file in 2 line  plugins { id('com.facebook.react.settings') } second issue is project gradle clean and gradle rebulid try but not working and show same error in ./gradle clean coomand

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

gradle version 8.8 is not use and there use gradle version 8.7 use and 8.7 to down version is not supported by project.enter image description here

Please put your original text in a translator because what you wrote here is incomprehensible even with the help of the screenshot.
